# Как сверстать адаптивно?

Tags: css3, html5

```css
.remo {
  margin-top: 90px; }

.remo-block {
  background-image: url("../img/score.png");
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 708px;
  height: 494px;
  max-height: 494px; }

.footer__text {
  color: #555555;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Roman";
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  min-width: 730px; }

.footer__text2 {
  color: #555555;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Roman";
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 35px 26px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center; }
  .footer__text2 span {
    margin-left: 30px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: #4d76a1;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px; }

.aw {
  background-color: #e23939;
  width: 368px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 25px; }

.aw__span {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Bold";
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 47px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  display: block; }

.aw__span2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Roman";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 67px;
  display: block; }

.aw__span3 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue Cyr - Roman";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px; }

.aw__span4 {
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 60px; }

.aw__span5 {
  margin-bottom: 40px; }

.aw__span6 {
  margin-bottom: 49px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="remo">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="remo-block">
     
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A6a853304f9d296d0ec4add0a3a82f8fc07566b1f15331ad6f8d4fd15fbaca79b&amp;width=600&amp;height=494&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=false"></script>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>


<div class="aw">
 <span class="aw__span">
  Бип Авто
 </span>
 <span class="aw__span2">
  Центр по  ремонту и продаже 
  стартеров, генератов
 </span>
 <span class="aw__span3">
  г. Тольятти <br>
  ул. Комсомольская, 159
 </span>
 <span class="aw__span3 aw__span4">
  Время работы: <br>
  пн-пт 09:00 - 18:00 <br>
  суб 10:00 - 15:00 <br>
 </span>
 <span class=' aw__span3 aw__span5'>
  8(8482) 46-70-05 <br>
  8(8482) 49-40-06 <br>
  8(8482) 47-58-03 <br>
 </span>
 <span class="aw__span3 aw__span6">
  email: bipavto@mail.ru
 </span>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Надо сделать как на картинке. блоки сверстал а как расположить правильно с учетом адаптива не знаю**

Comment: В чём вопрос-то?

Comment: @humster_spb спасибо что откликнулись, хотел вставить картинку как надо и комп завис ...

Comment: @humster_spb  что делать тут не отображается правильно т.к мобильный экран ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, я бы на Вашем месте красный блок перенёс внутрь section class="remo" и спозиционировал его абсолютно, чтобы он лёг поверх картинки и карты посередине. А с помощью медиа-запроса для экранов меньше 767px отменил бы позиционирование (а ещё в коде карты я бы заменил фиксированную ширину в 600px на auto, потому что фиксированная ширина несовместима с адаптивной вёрсткой):

```css
.remo {
  padding-top: 90px;
  position: relative;
}
.remo-block {
  background-image: url("https://onlinekassa.guru/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/nuzhna-li-onlajn-kassa-dlya-avtoservisa1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 708px;
  height: 494px;
  max-height: 494px; }

.aw {
  background-color: #e23939;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  }

.aw__span {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Bold";
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block; }

.aw__span2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Roman";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 67px;
  display: block; }

.aw__span3 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue Cyr - Roman";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px; }

.aw__span4 {
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 50px; }

.aw__span5 {
  margin-bottom: 30px; }

.aw__span6 {
  margin-bottom: 40px; }
 
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .remo {
       padding-top: 0;
     }
     .aw {
       position: static;
     }
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="remo">
<div class="aw">
 <span class="aw__span">
  Бип Авто
 </span>
 <span class="aw__span2">
  Центр по  ремонту и продаже 
  стартеров, генератов
 </span>
 <span class="aw__span3">
  г. Тольятти <br>
  ул. Комсомольская, 159
 </span>
 <span class="aw__span3 aw__span4">
  Время работы: <br>
  пн-пт 09:00 - 18:00 <br>
  суб 10:00 - 15:00 <br>
 </span>
 <span class=' aw__span3 aw__span5'>
  8(8482) 46-70-05 <br>
  8(8482) 49-40-06 <br>
  8(8482) 47-58-03 <br>
 </span>
 <span class="aw__span3 aw__span6">
  email: bipavto@mail.ru
 </span>
</div>

 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="remo-block">
     
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A6a853304f9d296d0ec4add0a3a82f8fc07566b1f15331ad6f8d4fd15fbaca79b&amp;width=auto&amp;height=494&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=false"></script>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, извините сейчас занят, будет свободное время, посмотрю ваше решение, поможет, поставлю лайк

Comment: спасибо за поомщь